# Dockerのubuntuでlanguage-pack-ja-baseがインストールできない

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Docker上のubuntu:latest(16.04)で`apt-get install language-pack-ja-base`を実行すると
`Unable to locate package language-pack-ja-base`というエラーが発生します

どうすれば`language-pack-ja-base`をインストールできますか?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt-get update` を実行すれば、 `apt-get install language-pack-ja-base` できるようになります。